# check wether a javascript DOM Element is rendered in the page or not

Tags: javascript, html, dom

i am trying to check if a DOM js element is present in the html page or not. Something like this:

```js
var a = document.querySelector('div'),
    b = document.createElement('div');
    
var f = () => {
  // some code
}
```

```html
<div>hello world</div>
```

essentially, doing `f(a)` should return `true`, but doing `f(b)` should return `false`.

is this possible? thanks.

Comment: You don't need a separate function; `document.querySelector(...)` will do exactly what you want: return the element if a match exists, or `null` otherwise.

Comment: @ChrisG - I think their starting point is an element instance rather than a selector, but I could be mistaken.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder True, looks like it

Comment: it is, however I could also use querySelector since I also have a function in my code that finds the selector starting from the element (using: nth-child), thanks for the suggestion @T.J.Crowder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) method to do that, calling it on `document`.

```js
const
    a = document.querySelector('div'),
    b = document.createElement('div');
    
const f = element => {
    return document.contains(element);
};

console.log(f(a)); // true
console.log(f(b)); // false
```

```html
<div>hello world</div>
```

Alternatively, you could follow the element's `parentNode` until either it's `null` (no further parent) or it's `document`:

```js
const
    a = document.querySelector('div'),
    b = document.createElement('div');
    
const f = node => {
    let inDom = false;
    while (node && node.parentNode) {
        if (node.parentNode === document) {
            inDom = true;
            break;
        }
        node = node.parentNode;
    }
    return inDom;
};

console.log(f(a)); // true
console.log(f(b)); // false
```

```html
<div>hello world</div>
```

Comment: thanks for you answer, that i found very useful, does ```document.contains(document.querySelector('head'))``` returns true?, i mean, does you code work also with tags that are not inside the body one?

Comment: @Giuppox - Yes. `document` contains `head` and `body`, and so indirectly contains all the elements within `head` and `body`. (Indeed, when I first posted the answer, for no good reason I can think of I used `document.body.contains` then realized that was silly and went back to fix it. :-) )

Comment: thanks, you gave me a huge help, what if (i know i should not do it but, you never know!) i put a tag that it is not head or body inside the html?

Comment: @Giuppox - Most likely the browser will relocate it to `body`, but even if it doesn't, it *should* still be within `document`. But when you do invalid things, you get varying results across browsers, and sometimes the results aren't what you want. :-)